# Will a Node.js app consuming a JSON file share in-memory between connections?

Tags: json, node.js, memory

I am trying to decide between holding static data (gets updated on a nightly basis, not real-time) in a database or in flat JSON files to supply a Node.js application. In preliminary tests the flat file method is twice as fast. My question is about the issue of memory when using the file method.

If my Node.js app reads the data from the file and then does `JSON.parse` and passes the object to the template to render... does the in-memory size of that data get duplicated with each user connection?

i.e. if the data file is 1MB and there are 1000 concurrent users, does it consume 1000MB of server memory during that period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each connection runs separately so if you have 1000 concurrent users, they aren't really running their request all at the same time because node.js is single threaded.  It runs one single connection until it either finishes or until it hits a non-blocking operation such as async I/O.  Assuming you are using async file I/O, you could have a few connections in process at the same time, but as soon as one finishes, its memory use will be returned to the system by the garbage collector.

Your operation sounds ideal for an in-memory cache.  You can decide what lifetime works best for the cache, but you could load the JSON, store it in memory, set an expiration time 10 minutes from now and as long as the current time is not greater than the expiration time, you just return the result from the cache with no disk access.   Thus, you'd only ever retrieve the data from disk once every 10 minutes max and the data would be returned even faster and the average memory used per request would be significantly lower.

The only downside to this cache approach is that when the data is updated real-time, it could take up to 10 minutes (on average 1/2 the cache time or 5 minutes) for the cached data to expire and the new data to be returned.  Since this only happens once nightly, it may not be a big deal to you, but there are ways to deal with that issue if you want to.  For example, you can check the file date/time of the data file on every request and if it hasn't changed since the last time, then you just keep using your cached version of the data.  When it does change, you read it from the disk and replace the cached version.  This adds an extra disk I/O operation on each request, but guarantees that the user always gets the latest version while still allowing for the benefits of a cached version that only has to be newly read into memory when the data has actually changed.

---

One other thing to consider.  If the data is 1MB and you're generating a giant HTML file from that, your page rendering may be where the largest memory consumption is since expanding a large data structure into HTML can often make it 10-20x larger and how well your rendering engine does with memory consumption depends entirely on the rendering engine.

If there is no per-user customization in the HTML or anything else in the rendered HTML that varies from one rendering to the next (as long as the JSON hasn't changed), you might want to actually cache the rendered HTML so all you have to do is stream it to each request.

Comment: Though this is something I would want to believe. I have noticed Node.JS reaching 3GB on an application on production that isn't really doing anything. Which is really sad.

Comment: @majidarif - 3GB and not really doing anything?  I doubt it.  It obviously did something to cause that much memory to be used.  It's either leaking, holding large data or caches in memory or used a lot of memory at one time and has lots of free memory available for future use and just hasn't returned it to the OS.  I have a node.js web application running on a raspberry pi that only uses about 88MB and only has a total of 180MB free to even run in.

Comment: Awesome answer, @jfriend00! Thanks for the thorough explanation. The in-memory cache sounds like it might end up being the best option for this situation. BTW, it is a UI-heavy search tool. The data is basically just products and their filterable properties, segmented by category. The 1MB was just a round number for example purposes.